# Как получить переменную после вывода сообщений в инлайновой клавиатуре?

Tags: python, telebot

[image]Столкнулся с проблемой добавление обработчика в инлайновую клавиатуру, хотел сделать так чтобы после выбора какой-нибудь кнопки, пользователь смог ввести переменную чтобы в последующих действиях можно было эту переменную использовать в математических вычислениях

Comment: Пожалуйста, отправьте свой полный исходный код(ну либо хотябы момент где у Вас считываються сообщения и появляеться сама клавиатура) текстом, тогда я смогу Вам помочь!

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете заставить бота ожидать сообщение от пользователя с помощью метода `bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, func)`, после чего передать сообщение в функцию.